# Jest ReferenceError: Request is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I know this has been asked but I'm having this error with node 18 and polyfill for Request or fetch should not be needed.

I have the following test in jest:

```
describe('Strange error', () => {
  it('Why', async () => {
    console.log('Node.js version:', process.version);
    expect(Request).not.toBeUndefined();
  });
});
```

Output is:

```
console.log
Node.js version: v18.14.0

  at Object.log (file.spec.tsx:3:13)

FAIL   test  file.spec.tsx
  Strange error
    ✕ Why (11 ms)

  ● Strange error › Why

    ReferenceError: Request is not defined

      2 |   it('Why', async () => {
      3 |     console.log('Node.js version:', process.version);
    > 4 |     expect(Request).not.toBeUndefined();
        |            ^
      5 |   });
      6 | });
```

My jest.config is:

```
module.exports = {
  testRegex:
    'file.spec.tsx',
  transform: {
    '^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)': 'jest-preview/transforms/file',
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom', //when commented out this works
};
```

Comment: @Craicerjack It's [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) just like fetch it should be available in node as well as in (most) browsers.

Comment: @Craicerjack Found that if I don't add `testEnvironment: 'jsdom'` it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jest has an [outdated](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Bug+Report%2CNeeds+Triage&projects=&template=bug.yml&title=%5BBug%5D%3A+) jsdom config because it uses outdated [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1724).

I applied the sollution [here](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1724#issuecomment-1446858041) and it works as long as I add the ts file in the jest config as testEnvironment but won't if I want to use it for a [single test](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string) since

```
/**
 * @jest-environment ./src/test/my-custom-environment
 */
```

Isn't doing anything, tried different paths and different files (mjs, cjs, js) but the whole thing is just ignored, even a non existing file won't produce an error.

The solution:

```
// FixJSDOMEnvironment.ts
import JSDOMEnvironment from 'jest-environment-jsdom';

export default class FixJSDOMEnvironment extends JSDOMEnvironment {
  constructor(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof JSDOMEnvironment>) {
    super(...args);

    this.global.fetch = fetch;
    this.global.Headers = Headers;
    this.global.Request = Request;
    this.global.Response = Response;
  }
}

// jest.config.js
const config = {
  testEnvironment: './FixJSDOMEnvironment.ts',
  ...
}
```